# How to check whether a customer id is present or not

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am making a booking system application for a sports club. In my SQL Server database, I have two tables; one is named `Memberships` and the other is named `Bookings`.

Now, what I want is to allow a new booking for only those customers who have a membership. In the database I have joined both tables by the `cust_id` attribute where the `Memberships` table is parent and `Bookings` table is child. I want that when a new booking is tried, then it should first check if the customer ID is present in database. If it is present, then the booking should be allowed, otherwise not. But, my code shows an error first and then allows the booking

Here is my code for this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim str2 As String  ' defines string variable for taking select query

str2 = "select Memberships.cust_id, booking_date, booking_time, booking_duration, game, poolno, courtno, tableno from Bookings, Memberships where Memberships.cust_id = Bookings.cust_id"

i = -1
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(str2, con)                   'defines a new sql command with str2 as query string and con as connection string
con.Open()                                              'sets the connection state to open

Dim bookchk As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader       'Defines and initiates the datareader to read data from database using cmd2 command
While bookchk.Read() 
    If Me.MskdTxtCustId.Text = bookchk("cust_id") Then
        i = 1
    End If
End While

bookchk.Close()
con.Close()

If i = -1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Error")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just ask for the customers membership number before they can make a booking?

Otherwise you could make membership number a required field.

I could understand if you'd got as far as checking the database if it was a case of checking if the membership number they gave was valid, otherwise check for required data before connecting to a database.

Comment: by the way.. your str2 would be better as 
str2 = "SELECT b.* FROM bookings AS b INNER JOIN memberships AS m ON b.cust_id = m.cust_id"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim sql As String
Dim customerIDyouWantToCheck As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

sql = "select cust_id from Memberships where Memberships.cust_id = '" & customerIDyouWantToCheck & "'"

Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(str2, con)   
con.Open()

Dim bookchk As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader     
If bookchk.HasRows() Then
    i = 1
Else
    i = -1
EndIf
```

I'm assuming you know the ID of the customer who you want to make a booking for. Otherwise I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: Actually the reader is not just reading the cust_id rather it is reading all the values which are mentioned in the query given by me...Some other validations are being made using those values I just posted the code which is related to my probvlem

Comment: I think error lies in this part 
            If bookchk("cust_id") Is Me.MskdTxtCustId.Text Then
                i = 1
            End If                                                  as if i'm executing the bookchk("cust_id") simply and displaying its result in message box then it shows the value of cust_id vut when the if condition is implemented it doesn't even enter the if condition like if in comparison part the values don't match

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with anything like this is to ensure the database returns what you want first.  Have you tried the run the query directly against sql-server?

What you really need is to check the customers ID in the Membership table **first**, and once the correct customer is established separately go ahead an insert into the Bookings table. **These are both atomic transactions**.

I think you are making this simply problem too complex.

Answer (score 0):

Loading all booking/membership combinations and looping through them to find a certain customer ID is bad practice.
It is better to query for the desired customer ID directly. Plus, you should use SQL parameters instead of string concatenation to pass the customer ID to the query.

Before:

```
str2 = "select [...] where Memberships.cust_id = Bookings.cust_id"

i = -1
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(str2, con)
```

After:

```
str2 = "select [...] where Memberships.cust_id = Bookings.cust_id and Bookings.cust_id = @CustomerID"

i = -1
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(str2, con)  
cmd2.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Me.MskdTxtCustId.Text)
```

---

**Regarding your actual problem:**

> but my code either shows error first and then allows the booking

As you didn't show the code that does the booking and how it is connected to the code you showed, we can't tell how you use the result from the code you posted to determine if the booking is done or not.

You should wrap the code that you posted in a method that returns true or false, depending whether the booking is allowed or not.

```
'the CustomerHasMembership() method contains the code you posted and 
'returns true when the customer DOES have a membership
If CustomerHasMembership(Me.MskdTxtCustId.Text) Then 
    DoBooking()
End If
```